# How to map applications listening on various ports to specifIc URL using HAproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I know I have asked this before but I dint get any answers.So Let's say if an app called "page-designer" is listening at http://IP:30000, then it should map it to http://IP/page-designer. How can I do this in HAproxy?I mean is there any sort of configuration to be done in the main config file for this to be achievable?Plz help

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg(I havent changed anything so far in the config file)

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend fe_default
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    acl pagedesigner path_beg -i /page-designer

    use_backend bk_pagedesigner if pagedesigner

backend bk_pagedesigner
    server appserver1 206.189.22.155:5000
```

How can I configure and map the application to specific URL's?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use ACLs to help you create conditionals similar to the following:

```
global
    (...)
defaults
    (...)
frontend fe_default
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt certificate.pem
    acl pagedesigner path_beg -i /page-designer

    use_backend bk_pagedesigner if pagedesigner

(...)
backend bk_pagedesigner
    server appserver1 1.2.3.4:30000 ssl check
```

(My example is for a TLS secured environment, but the principle is the same if you want to do it in plaintext).

Comment: so i just add this to the config file and restart the haproxy again?

Comment: and in place of 0.0.0.0:443 instead of 0.0.0.0 should I replace it with my IP address of my server?

Comment: i getting parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:40] : 'bind 0.0.0.0:443' : unable to load SSL certificate file '/etc/ssl/private/certificate.pem' file does not exist.
[ALERT] 246/083127 (14978) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 246/083127 (14978) : Fatal errors found in configuration.

Comment: You will have to understand the product too - never ever just cut and paste something from the Internet and use it in a production environment. `0.0.0.0` is shorthand for "all IPv4 interfaces". This may or may not be what you want. Regarding the certificate file: If you haven't got one you can either create a certificate (https://letsencrypt.org is a good starting point), or - if you truly don't care - remove the TLS-specific parts of the configuration. Again, the HAProxy documentation is your friend.

Comment: actually for the time being I want to do this using http instead of SSL.So in that case, I would not have to worry about creating a certificate file right??

Comment: Exactly. Then you would just remove the SSL/TLS parts of the listener and backend server configurations.

Comment: Hi can you modify your example to use http instead of the SSL/TLS parts?

Comment: As I wrote earlier: If you're going to create a production environment, you will need to know how the products you use work, or they will come back and bite you in the future. Follow the following link to the manual for the current (september 2019) production version for more information and some examples: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html

Comment: hi i just updated my config file

Comment: hitting http://206.189.22.155/page-designer is now showing "Cannot GET /page-designer"

Comment: if i use server appserver1 1.2.3.4:5000 for the back end the hitting 206.189.22.155/page-designer  is showing 503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: Do you have anything listening to the path /page-designer on the backend server? Remember that HAProxy is a reverse proxy and by default makes the same request to the backend server that the client requests from HAProxy. If that’s not what you want you will need to rewrite the requested path, either in HAProxy, using `http-request set-path` (see the manual) or in the backend server.

Comment: i have nothing listening at the path /page-designer

Comment: My task is simple.I just want to map a node js application running on my ubuntu server at  206.189.22.155:5000 to 206.189.22.155/page-designer.

Comment: the reason why i want to do this is because there are a lot of ports blocked on my ubuntu server.Mapping them this way helps me to avoid the issue regarding these ports being blocked on my server!!

Comment: currently i will do this manually in the config file for this page-designer app.But later on i will have to figure out a way to do this dynamically